# How to allow self service role selection for Azure/Office365 application assignment

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-marketplace

In Microsoft Azure, I can add an application from the marketplace to my Active Directory. For example let's say 'Salesforce'.
I can enable SSO and Provisioning and particularly Self Service.
The steps to setup self service are here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-self-service-application-access

Those steps are for the old portal, but I used the new portal, it's mostly the same.

Some applications, like Salesforce, have multiple roles that can be assigned, and when you add a user or group an assignment you select a role. As far as I can tell, you can only enable self service features to put a user directly into a single specific group, and that group dictates the role that is assigned.

**My question is:**
Is there a way to allow the end user, when requesting an application, to pick the role they want? Even if it is a bit round-about, like picking a group that assigns the role. Or is azure self-service limited to granting access to one specific role?